# How can I smooth the thresholding process in real time?

Tags: python, opencv, video, threshold

Firstly ı want to find the change of water dripping time into the fabric with camera.User will drip water to the fabric after that algorithm detect the movement until water absorb completely and plot the graph change-time with showing the absorbation time,area etc..

In order to do detect movement I have used absdif function with constant change rate.And I take  frames start time of detection to the end [like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdAqv.png).There is no problem in here.But in order to calculate the absorbation of water I thresholded frame and use countNonZero function to calculate the number of black pixel .  But there is one problem here,the black pixels that shown red lines of [thresholded images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9rhV.png)  are continuosly changing(like shaking,vibration etc).So plotting process is fail.

### Try

1. I tried to change webcam device(using phone camera by İpcam)
2. I tried to adaptive threshold methods(otsu etc) to find optimum threshold
3. Smoothing lightning conditions and capturing without background

### Success

1. When I use the video that was taken by phone camera as input, shaking and vibration effects decreases and I can reach the success [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY7oB.png) as expected

### QUESTION

- How can I smooth the thresholded image in real time
- Another approach

### Code

```
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import operator

def pixelHesaplayici(x):
    siyaholmayanpixel=cv2.countNonZero(x)
    height,width=x.shape
    toplampixel=height*width
    siyahpixelsayisi=toplampixel-siyaholmayanpixel
    return siyahpixelsayisi

def grafikciz(sure,newblackpixlist,maxValue,index,totaltime,cm):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
    plt.plot(sure,newblackpixlist)
    line,=plt.plot(sure,newblackpixlist)
    plt.setp(line,color='r')
    plt.text(totaltime/2,maxValue/2, r'$Max- 
    Pixel=%d$'%maxValue,fontsize=14,color='r')
    plt.text(totaltime/2,maxValue/2.5, r'$Max-emilim- 
    zamanı=%f$'%sure[index],fontsize=14,color='b')
    plt.text(totaltime/2,maxValue/3, r'$Max- 
    Alan=%fcm^2$'%cm,fontsize=14,color='g')
    plt.ylabel('Black Pixels')
    plt.xlabel('Time(s)')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()


static_back=None
i=0
blackpixlist=[]
newblackpixlist=[]

t=[]
video=cv2.VideoCapture("kumas1.mp4")

while(True):
    ret,frame=video.read()

    if ret==True:
        gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
        _,threshforgraph=cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,
       cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
        if static_back is None:
            static_back=gray
            continue
        diff_frame=cv2.absdiff(static_back,gray)

        threshfortime=cv2.threshold(diff_frame,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        #threshfortime=cv2.dilate(threshfortime,None,iterations=2)
        (_,cnts,_)=cv2.findContours(threshfortime.copy(),
                               cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        for contour in cnts:
            if cv2.contourArea(contour)<450:
                continue
            an=datetime.now()
            t.append(an.minute*60+an.second+(an.microsecond/1000000))
            cv2.fillPoly(frame,contour, (255,255,255), 8,0)
            cv2.imwrite("samples/frame%d.jpg"%i,threshforgraph)


            i+=1


        cv2.imshow("org2",frame)
        #cv2.imshow("Difference Frame",diff_frame)
        #cv2.imshow("Threshold Frame",threshfortime)
        #cv2.imshow("Threshforgraph",threshforgraph)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
ti=t[1::3]

lasttime=ti[-1]
firsttime=ti[-len(ti)]
totaltime=lasttime-firsttime

for i in range(0,i):
        img=cv2.imread('samples/frame%d.jpg'%i,0)
        blackpixlist.append(pixelHesaplayici(img))
ilkpix=blackpixlist[0]

for a in blackpixlist:
    newblackpixlist.append(a-ilkpix)
newblackpixlisti=newblackpixlist[1::3]  
index , maxValue=max(enumerate(newblackpixlisti),
key=operator.itemgetter(1))
sure=np.linspace(0,totaltime,len(newblackpixlisti))
cm=0.0007*maxValue # For 96 dpi

grafikciz(sure,newblackpixlisti,maxValue,index,totaltime,cm)
```

Comment: Have you considered floodfilling? Try for example https://www.learnopencv.com/filling-holes-in-an-image-using-opencv-python-c/

Comment: The absorbation frame is not exact circle they are amorphous. And we need the area of changıng shape everytıme. Black pixel of Thresholded caps shaking and changıng even ıf no movement is it normal thing.

Answer (score 0):

What about subtracting the first frame from the next frames? If you can know or can detect when there is no drop and subtract it, the difference will only give you the result of the drop.

This approach might be interesting also if you have several drops in different places and want discard the previous drop.
Note that you can do the subtraction before and after thresholding. I would recommend before thresholding.

If you know that you have a lot of shaking in your process, you probably need to apply a digital stabilization, in which case I would advise to look at this tutorial:
https://www.learnopencv.com/video-stabilization-using-point-feature-matching-in-opencv/

Of course, the stabilization should be done before the subtraction.

In general for your problem, I wouldn't use an adaptive method. The threshold should be the same for all frames, if it adapts depending on the image, you could have invalid results.

I hope I properly understood your problem!

Comment: Brilliant approach to find max Black pixel but ı need the tıme knowledge of movement so ı must know the stop movement tıme. Actually in this aproach ı using 2 threshold functıon(one of counting non zero pixel for graph, other one is to detect movement). But faıl. Because of the shaking pixel, the detecting function detect movement always and ı see infinite time of movement. On the other hand Accordıng the fabric type, my threshold value must be changed İn your approach actually I fail completely with my bad documentation. How can I optimize this system ım New on python